# UpdateAll and HABTM in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models and a join table, `User`, `Post` and `posts_users`.

The `posts_users` table contains a few extra fields, one of which is `is_active`. I want to set all of a users posts to active providing the user is active themselves.

I have the following

```
$this->Post->PostsUser->updateAll(array('PostsUser.is_active' => 1), array('PostsUser.user_id' => $data['User']['id'], 'User.is_active' => 1));
```

Which causes a MySQL error

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.is_active' in 'where clause' ...
>
> Query: UPDATE `posts_sites` AS `PostsUser` SET `PostsUser`.`is_active` = 1 WHERE `PostsUser`.`user_id` = 1 AND `User`.`is_active` = 1

As you can see the User table isn't getting joined in the query. Is there away around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you defined the `PostsUser` model explicitly, or are you just using the implicitly auto-generated model?

It seems the latter is the case, so that model will probably not have any associations. You could bind them on the fly before making the update call, or you could explicitly create the model file and define the associations.

I.e. the `Post` and `User` models are connected to each other, but the `PostsUser` model is just an empty helper model that dangles off of either of them. It does not by itself have any connections, so when making a call from `PostsUser` it has no defined associations.

```
  Post   <--->   User
    |             |
    v             v
PostsUser     PostsUser
```

Comment: It was an auto-generated model, I've created the model file with the appropriate associations and now it's working, Nice job!